# write a SQL query to retrieve third row from the table in ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle

write a SQL query to retrieve third row from the table  ,Let 's say table name is `emp`
Actually i want to understand `rownum` concept

```
Select * from 
 (select rownum r ,e.* from emp e ) 
 where r = 3 ;
```

and it works well

Once i try this

```
select * from 
( select rownum , e.* from emp e ) 
where rownum = 3 ;
```

i'm getting my output : `no data found`

could you explain please , Thanks in advance

Comment: You must hand it to the tutors they are imaginative!

Answer (score 1):

First of all no need of including `rownum` in your inner query. From [Oracle documentation for ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm) a small excerpt

> Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer
>   are always false. For example, this query returns no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE ROWNUM > 1;
```

> The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the
>   condition false. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and
>   is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false. All rows
>   subsequently fail to satisfy the condition, so no rows are returned.

I believe, that's the same thing happening for your case as well with the condition `WHERE ROWNUM = 3`.

The first row fetched is assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false cause `1 != 3`. The second row to be fetched is now the first row and is also assigned a ROWNUM of 1 and makes the condition false cause again `1 != 3` and so on ...

It's recommended to use [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#i86310) instead for this purpose.

Comment: Hi ,rahul but my question is once i'm using rownum with alias it works , but once i'm using rownum without alias ,it is not working .

Comment: @Maverick, in your first case using alias `where r = 3` is considered as a column from derived/inner table and so it works but in 2nd case `where rownum = 3` even if you think you are using the derived table rownum column; it's actually using the `rownum` pseudo column and per my answer you know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually i want to understand rownum concept
```

Each query has its own rownum. ROWNUM is not a real column that propagates from the inside query to the outside. ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn for each query and is valid within that query scope only. The inner rownum is rownum.1, the outer rownum is rownum.2, they are not the same, so you are dealing with 2 separate columns. I you had 3 queries, nested, you would have 3 rownums. The outer ROWNUM shadows the inner ROWNUM. To pass ROWNUM from an inner subquery to an outer query requires you to alias the column to something besides a pseudocolumn, otherwise the column is "redefined" with each outer query.

Your query could be thought of as:

```
select rownum, subquery.sub_rownum, subquery.empno from 
( select rownum as sub_rownum, e.* from emp e ) subquery
where subquery.sub_rownum = 3 
;
```

Notice there are now 2 "rownum" columns. The inner rownum, by its alias, sub_rownum, appears to be a real column to the outer queries. Notice the use of rownum again in the outer query. They are 2 different variables. Note the values 1 and 3. ROWNUM = 1 on the outside because its the 1st row in the outer result set. SUB_ROWNUM = 3 because it was the 3rd result in the inner result set, and since you aliased it, it survived to bubble up as a real column.

```
    ROWNUM SUB_ROWNUM      EMPNO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3       7521
```

Answer (score -1):

For SQL Server:
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber, e.*
     FROM dbo.tbl_emp e
)demo
WHERE demo.RowNumber=3